# Proof of Cauchy– Schwarz inequality

Tags: complex-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Theorem:

If $a_1 , ... , a_n$ and $b_1 , ... , b_n$ are complex numbers, then

$$|\sum(a_jb_j^\ast)|^2\le\sum(|a_j|^2)\sum(|b_j|^2)$$

where  $b_j^*$ is the conjugate of  $b_j$ .

Put $A = \sum(|a_j|^2)$ , $B = \sum(|b_j|^2)$  , $C = \sum(a_jb_j^*)$

## Proof:

To prove that inequality my book shows this equation:

$$\sum(|Ba_j - Cb_j|^2) = B(AB - |C|^2)$$

---

**My question is how can I obtain the LHS of the equation?**

Comment: Rufy, I don't understand what you mean by "
I try to obtain $\sum|Ba_j - Cb_j|$ but i'm not succeed". Can you explain (by editing your question, not posting a new answer) where you are starting from to get this $\sum|Ba_j - Cb_j|$? Also please explain why equation (2) of Willy K is not a complete answer to your problem?

Comment: I need a step by step solution  of this question "how I can obtained" $\sum|Ba_j - Cb_j|^2? "

Comment: Starting from the right hand side, correct? This is equation (2) Of Willy.K. Read it starting from the right, and go left.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly. Actually, I don't know if you are asking why does $\sum_{j=1}^{n}(|Ba_{j}-Cb_{j}|^{2})=B(AB-|C|^{2})$ hold or how can one obtain Schwartz inequality from it. I'm going to adress both problems.

Let $\langle x,y \rangle := x^{*}y$ denote the usual inner product in $\mathbb{C}$, so that $|z|^{2} \equiv z^{*}z = \langle z,z\rangle$. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
|Ba_{j}-Cb_{j}|^{2} = \langle Ba_{j}^{*}-C^{*}b_{j}^{*},Ba_{j}-Cb_{j}\rangle = B^{2}|a_{j}|^{2}-BCa_{j}^{*}b_{j}-BC^{*}a_{j}b_{j}^{*}+|C|^{2}|b_{j}|^{2} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
Using (\ref{1}), we have also:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}|Ba_{j}-Cb_{j}|^{2} &= B^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{j}|^{2}-BC\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}^{*}b_{j}-BC^{*}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}b_{j}^{*}+|C|^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|b_{j}|^{2} \\
&= B^{2}A-B|C|^{2}-B|C|^{2}+|C|^{2}B = B(BA-|C|^{2}) \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}
This proves your equation. Now, the other question is how to obtain Schwartz inequality from (\ref{2}). Well, note that $|Ba_{j}-Cb_{j}|^{2}\ge 0$ for every $j=1,...,n$, so that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}|Ba_{j}-Cb_{j}|^{2} \ge 0$. Thus, we must have:
$$B(BA-|C|^{2})\ge 0 $$
But, by definition, $B\ge 0$, so that, the above inequality implies $BA-|C|^{2}\ge 0$. But this means $|C|^{2}\le BA$, which is the same as:
\begin{eqnarray}
|\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}b_{j}^{*}|^{2} \le (\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{j}|^{2})(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|b_{j}|^{2})
\end{eqnarray}
and this is Schwartz inequality.

Comment: Thx for your answer but I need to know how I can obrained $\sum(|Ba_j - Cb_j|^2)$

Comment: You don't obtain it from anywhere actually. It is your starting point. You consider this sum, then show equations (1) and (2) of my post and then conclude Schwartz inequality.

Comment: Yes, it is my starting point but I need to  know how I can obtained it. Is the book author a magician?

Comment: It's kinda magic, indeed. The point is that he knew where it would get chosing this sum. There is nothing wrong about starting for some 'magic point', it just makes things less intuitive. There are other proofs that are way more intuitive than this one. For instance, you can check the first chapter of Kreyszig's book on functional analysis.